# How To: add new json content into a preexisting file following the same format inside an array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ionic-framework, fs

I am using Node.js for my server side and have passed back a json object to the server from teh client. I have gotten the data to add on to the end of the preexistin gfile, but i wan the data to be added into the file under the electricalAssest section.

This is the JSON file on the server side I wan tot add the data to.

```
{
"substation": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "geoLocation": "-33.7490, 84.3880",
        "supportAssetTypes": [
            {
                "id": "cs-1",
                "type": "capacitorStructure",
                "specifications": {
                    "construction": "galvanized steel",
                    "capacity": {
                        "x": 10,
                        "y": 2,
                        "z": 5
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "electricalAssetTypes": [
            {
                "id": "siemens-c1",
                "type": "capacitor",
                "specifications": {
                    "manufacture": "siemens",
                    "model": "1234",
                    "shape": "box",
                    "technology": "internally fused",
                    "ratedVoltage": 15,
                    "frequency": [
                        50,
                        60
                    ],
                    "ratedPower": [
                        {
                            "kvar": 1000,
                            "frequency": 50
                        },
                        {
                            "kvar": 1200,
                            "frequency": 60
                        }
                    ],
                    "maxCurrent": "180",
                    "BIL": [
                        95,
                        125,
                        150,
                        170,
                        200
                    ],
                    "dielectric": "Polypropylene film and oil",
                    "impregnant": "Biodegradable PCB-free oil",
                    "dischargeResistor": [
                        "75 V/10 min",
                        "50 V/5 min"
                    ],
                    "losses": 0.2,
                    "temperatureRange": [
                        -50,
                        55
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "supportAssets": [
            {
                "id": "struct121",
                "type": "cs-1",
                "location": {
                    "x": 1,
                    "y": 1,
                    "z": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "electricalAssets": [
            {
                "id": "c1",
                "assetType": "siemens-c1",
                "radioChs": [
                    101
                ],
                "installation": {
                    "supportAssetId": "struct121",
                    "slot": {
                        "x":"1",
                        "y":"1",
                        "z":"1"
                      }
                },
                "mounting": "horizontal"
            },
            {
                "id": "c2",
                "assetType": "siemens-c1",
                "radioChs": [
                    102
                ],
                "installation": {
                    "supportAssetId": "struct121",
                    "slot": {
                      "x":"2",
                      "y":"1",
                      "z":"1"
                    }
                },
                "mounting": "horizontal"
            }
        ]
    }]}
```

This is the function that calls adds the object to the end of the file in a long string.

```
router.post('', function(req, res, next) {
const token = req.headers['authorization'];
//const secretOrKey = 'your_jwt_secret';
if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).send({auth: false, message: 'No token provided.'});
}

jwt.verify(token, 'your_jwt_secret', function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(401).send({auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'});
    }
    else {
        if (decoded.role === 'admin' || decoded.role === 'engineer') {
            fs.readFile('configDB/configuration.json', (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                let json = JSON.parse(data);
                let object = JSON.stringify(req.body);
                //json.push('new capCan: ' + object);
                fs.appendFile("configDB/configuration.json", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)), function(err){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log(object);
                    res.send({ status: 'success'});
                });
            })
        }
        else {
            return res.status(500).send({admin: false, message: 'unauthorized to edit file'});
        }
    }
})
```

The code right now works but just adds the code to the very end of the file after the last "}". I want it to be inside the electricalAssets section in that same format.

Comment: read the file using `fs.readFile`, parse using `JSON.parse` , append your desired properties then save using `fs.writeFile(path , JSON.stringify(data))` the fs is just `require('fs')`

Comment: That is what I'm doing already/ have tried and it just adds a string to the end of the file. @Hudson

Comment: Yes that should be the extra JSON?

Comment: use `obj['electricalAssetTypes'][] = {  //your obj here  }`

Comment: When I do that I get [object object] added to the end of the file

Comment: @user9978520 take a look at `Object.assign`